# jQuery slideUp problem

Tags: jquery, slideup

So i keep getting the error "Object doesn't support this property or method". I can get the menu to slide down but I can't get it to slide up when my mouse leaves the menu. (#suggestions)

Here is my code: (jQuery 1.6)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function lookup(inputString) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
        $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {

                $('#suggestions').slideDown('slow');
                $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);

       // slideUp on mouseleave
        $('#suggestions').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#suggestions').slideUp('slow');
        });

            }

        });

    }

} // lookup


function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
```

Comment: how are these functions called?

Comment: Is this all of your script? And I see you're binding events inside your .post() call - what is it you're trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 1):

Are you wrapping this code in a ready handler?

```
$(function(){
  // all your stuff in here so all the elements you select exist before you assign handlers to them
});
```

If not, you can get inconsistent results depending on where you put your script.

**edit** actually, this won't matter in your case because you're only defining functions here.

Comment: I ended up putting this at the top of my script and it seems to work now.


`$(document).ready(function()
{
// Fade out the suggestions box when not active
$("#suggestions").mouseleave(function(){
setTimeout("$('#suggestions').slideUp('slow');", 200);
});
});
`

Comment: That makes sense - the $(document).ready(function() is essentially the same thing - the version I show is just shorthand. Then, rather than just defining functions you bound to the mouseleave event which just works when that event fires rather than having to call functions explicity.